# iterative variable losing value in nested loop

Tags: python

So I seem to be doing something incredibly dumb and I can't seem to figure it out.  I am trying to create script that will search a file for terms defined in another file.  This seems pretty basic to me but for some reason the outside loop iteration is empty on the inside loop.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    searchfile = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
    terms = open(sys.argv[2],"r")
    for line in searchfile:
        for term in terms:
            if re.match(term, line.rstrip()):
                print line
```

If I print line before the term loop it has the information.  If I print line inside the term loop, it doesn't.  What am I missing?

Comment: *empty*? As in, it's value is `None`? Please try to make your question as clear as possible by showing us exactly what is happening that you don't expect (expected output, actual output is usually a good strategy).

Comment: What is "the information" supposed to mean?

Comment: If `term` has trailing whitespace, it won't match `line.rstrip()`.

Comment: Sorry.  It seems to be printing blank lines as I seem to be getting a bunch of new lines but no text inside of the 2nd loop.  Nothing else.  Outside of the 2nd loop I get the full output of the sourcefile.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that files are iterators that get exhausted - this means that once they have been iterated over once, they will not restart from the beginning.

You are probably used to lists - iterables that return a new iterator each time you loop over them, from the beginning.

Files are single-use iterables - once you loop over them, they are exhausted.

You can either use `list()` to construct a list you can iterate over multiple times, or open the file inside the loop, so that it is reopened each time, creating a new iterator from the beginning.

Which option is best will vary depending on the use case. Opening the file and reading from disk will be slower, but making a list will require all the data being held in memory - if your file is extremely large, this may be a problem.

It's also worth noting that you should use [the `with` statement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4) when opening files in Python.

```
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as searchfile, open(sys.argv[2], "r") as terms:
    terms = list(terms)
    for line in searchfile:
        for term in terms:
            if re.match(term, line.rstrip()):
                print line
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'll correct the script accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

So what are you doing: In the first for-iteration you read the first line of `searchfile` and compare it with every line in `terms`, by reading the file `terms`. After that, the file `terms` is read completely, so in every next iteration of the searchfile-loop the terms-loop isn't executed any more (`terms` is 'empty').